# How to install xgboost in Rodeo GUI for a Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, xgboost

`xgboost` is recognized in terminal but not in Rodeo GUI

I've been trying to install `xgboost` since last night, but I just can't seem to get it to work. My latest development so far is that I am able to successfully call on the module when using the terminal, but it has an `ImportError` when using my Rodeo GUI, also in atom-hydrogren. Any tips how I can call `xgboost` for these?

Here 's a screencap for importing `xgboost`:

1. Success:

[image: Success!]

2. Failure:

   `>>> import xgboost
    ImportError: No module named xgboost`

Comment: Or if anyone can guide me to completely uninstalling xgboost if that would help.

Comment: How did you install it in the first place? Did you use `pip` or some other packaging manager?

Comment: Could you execute the following commands in rodeo and display the results: `from platform import python_version` and then `python_version()`

Comment: installed following this guide: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

Comment: Interesting, I have 2 different python versions. 2.7.10 from the one that works and 2.7.12 from the one that doesn't.

Comment: Did you install Anaconda as well?

Comment: yup been using python for data analysis with anaconda distribution for a while now, just tried to expand my toolkit with xgboost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodeo and Mac Terminal use different versions of Python and obviously different `PYTHONPATH` with their own set of libraries.

When you installed `xgboost` with `git`, you used the Terminal which is configured to use Python 2.7.10 (probably pre-installed with the OS). However, it is not installed in the package site that Rodeo uses.

You have two options:

1. Make Rodeo use the package site that the Terminal uses
2. Install `xgboost` in Rodeo's package site

Since you stated that Rodeo is installed alongside with Anaconda, I'd go with option 2. Anaconda has a lot of useful packages pre-installed that don't come along with the pre-installed libraries that the Terminal uses.

You could follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292484/xgboost-installation-issue-with-anaconda) to install `xgboost` in Anaconda. After which, it should work fine with Rodeo.

Otherwise, you could try this code directly in Rodeo:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install','xgboost'])
```

If `xgboost` cannot compile, then it means that you don't have a compatible compiler to build it. To build it in a Mac, do the following (provided you have Homebrew)

```
brew install gcc5 --without-multilib
```

and then install `xgboost` with `pip`.

Comment: Followed the link you provided and now I can import xgboost, but I get this error when loading pandas. 

ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96

Comment: @jbolilia Did you use `conda` or `pip`? Could you follow [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37025618/4565943) in that post.

Comment: also is there a way for me to just use one python? the anaconda path is exported in my `.bash_profile`. (`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/jbolilia/anaconda/bin`)

Comment: Yup I used `conda`! That's exactly the solution I followed. Asked me to downgrade some packages, pandas wasn't included.

Comment: @jbolilia Then try uninstalling it `conda remove xgboost` and then use the `pip` solution in Rodeo in my post.

Comment: @jbolilia *is there a way for me to just use one python?* Yes, that is what I did too, only that you would have to give preference to the Anaconda packages first like so: `export PATH=/Users/jbolilia/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I uninstalled xgboost, but it still doesn't recognize my pandas, so I can't run my rodeo IDE.

Comment: @jbolilia Does that mean you were able to run the Rodeo before but not after trying to install `xgboost` with `conda`?

Comment: Yes, I also use `atom` as my text editor sometimes with the `hydrogen` package which calls on my anaconda distribution. It also cannot recognize pandas after installing `xgboost` using `conda`.

You think I should just uninstall everything and do it all over again, if so how can I do this to ensure that all the files are definitely cleaned out?

Comment: @jbolilia Well, we can leave that for a last resort. For now, update `pandas` with `conda update pandas`, and try again, then report what you find.

Comment: Based on what I saw, it seems that `conda` install did not directly downgrade `pandas`, but did so four of its dependencies. I've updated `pandas` successfully and implemented the `pip` code above. However, I got this error: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/y4/q675pmbj4kj79h8cnz4vnpg00000gn/T/pip-build-blQ1lY/xgboost/
1`

Comment: This means you don't have a suitable compiler to build the `xgboost` package. Do you use Homebrew? If so, do `brew install gcc5 --without-multilib` in Terminal and then try again.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Does this also mean that `gcc` is my default compiler now?

Comment: @jbolilia Mabe so, but it should be for the best. So all is well now for both `xgboost` and `Rodeo`. PS: also make that `export` order switch so that even the `git` packages install at the right location in the future.

Comment: already, did the export switch. thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: @jbolilia Happy to help. Bear in mind that you are using Python 2.7; it's [end of life period](https://pythonclock.org/) is getting closer. You ought to consider switching to Python 3.x in the near future.

Comment: Yup, I have a 3.5 environment that I use sometimes, but I'll maybe use it more often. Thanks again!